# sum numbers in cells with condition in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

example:

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jJqAr0TNxeQRGP9e3jBpEQbMD_B4pyydi2Fz9RbDoy0/edit?usp=sharing)

Screenshot:

[image: sheet]

To `SUM` the numbers in `D11:F11` is easy and the result can be found at Section B.

But if I'd like to `SUM` the numbers in `D11:F11` with the condition that Identifiers in row 10 are <6, how to do that?

The final sum result would be 25.

Comment: `sumif` or `sumifs` as the names suggest :)

Comment: thanks but you can try, they don't work with cell's content mixed with numbers and strings.

Comment: that google sheet URL explains.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem and have provided another example as well below for understanding.

**First your problem.**

Screenshot: Please co-relate with the spreadsheet.

[image: Askers problem]

Formula used:

`=arrayformula(sum(value(iferror(regexextract(FILTER(D70:F70,D69:F69<6), "[a-z]*(\d*)[a-z]*")))))`

**Another Sample problem:** To extract D2 and D3

[image: sample]

Formula used:

`=arrayformula(sum(value(iferror(regexextract(FILTER(D61:G61,D62:G62 > 3), "[A-Z]*(\d*)[A-Z]*")))))`

Hope it works. Comment if I misunderstood your requirements.